# Modify and import as numpy.ndarray a txt file in python

Tags: python, data-importer

To import the data contained into the file `my_file.txt` that have the form:

```
Label[0] = 0.980252
Label[1] = -nan
Label[2] = -nan
Label[3] = -nan
Label[4] = 0.664706
Label[5] = -nan
Label[6] = -nan
Label[7] = -nan
Label[8] = -nan
Label[9] = -nan
Label[10] = -nan
Label[11] = 0.800183
Label[12] = -nan
Label[13] = -nan
Label[14] = -nan
Label[15] = 0
Mean Data = 15
```

I wrote the following code:

```
import numpy as np

with open('myfile.txt', 'r') as file_txt_original:
    data = file_txt_original.read()

    data = data.replace('Mean data', '-1')
    data = data.replace('Label[', '')
    data = data.replace(']', '')
    data = data.replace(' = ', ', ')

    file_txt_original.close()

with open('new_file.txt', 'w') as file_txt_copy:

    file_txt_copy.write(data)
    file_txt_copy.close()

my_array = np.loadtxt('new_file.txt', delimiter=',')
```

It works but this to me seems still quite an tricky solution... Any suggestion to improve this code without doing so many replacement or without saving an additional structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't quite get why the data is written out into a new file again; it
would be more "typical" to parse each line and create the array
simultaneously.

That said, apart from that concern the only other thing I'd like to
point out is that the `close` calls on the file objects aren't necessary
because you (absolutely correctly) already put them in a `with` block,
so that the `close` method will be automatically called if the block is
exited.

Edit:

Okay, so for clarification, I mean something like the following:

```
import re

import numpy as np

with open('myfile.txt', 'r') as file_txt_original:
    my_array = np.array([])

    for line in file_txt_original:
        matches = re.match("Label\[(\d+)] = (.*)", line)
        if matches:
            index, value = matches.groups()
            index = int(index)
            if index >= my_array.size:
                my_array.resize(index + 1)
            my_array[index] = float(value)
```

Obviously it would be much better to the size of the array from the
start, or maybe collecting things into a list and only allocate the
array at the end.

Comment: Yes, thanks, I tried to follow your suggestion, but I can not find any function to load the string 'data' into a numpy array without saving it before in txt and after having performed the modifications. Maybe I am missing something easy...

Comment: See the edit for a clarification on what I meant to say.

Answer (score 2):

You can concatenate the replace strings after you open the file, it will give better visibility

```
data = file_txt_original.read()
.replace('Mean data', '-1')
.replace('Label[', '')
.replace(']', '')
.replace(' = ', ', ')
```